# Chrome refuses to open and claims my dapp website is malicious

Tags: web3js, metamask, javascript, dapp-debugging

I just deployed a simple dapp on which users can connect their wallet and deploy their own ERC20 token. However, when I click the link of my website, Chrome doesn't open it and I get a red page telling me that the website is malicious...

Does anyone know how I can fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Was it deployed on a fresh domain, or a host that's already in disrepute? Is your smart contract malicious in any way?

Comment: Make sure it's https not http